# My first meta puzzle (as I remember)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, metapuzzles

I don't have any comments about this question, all info are in the image.

[image]

Hint 1:

> 2 of 3 puzzles use A1Z26.

Comment: Let me guess... 2 involves hex codes. Am I right, @IsaacRoanSison?

Comment: rot13(2. vf ORYYL (pbybe inyhr qrp/10 + N1M26) naq 3. vf YVGRE (uvqqra jbeqf "bar" "phovp" "qrpvzrgre" = 1 yvgre/yvger) - sbe 1., hfvat ovanel gura N1M26 lvryqf va abguvat hfrshx)

Comment: @LukasRotter better call Sir Francis Bacon for that one. :)